# Should a new rear shock be building oil in the shaft?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, full-suspension, shocks

I've ridden my new bike (first full suspension I own) for about 150km now and I'm seeing some oil building over the O-ring in the shaft. It's a lot more oil than what you normally see on a front suspension, so I'm starting to worry about it, but it can be just my ignorance :p

Is this normal or should I send it back to the manufacturer? it's still on warranty.

There is no dripping while stored, so it's maybe only about wiping out the excess after every ride. Or the few first rides?

The shock is a [RockShox Monarch RT](https://www.sram.com/rockshox/products/monarch-rt)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is definitely not right. Send it back for repair.

Similar to front shocks, a good shock will have a very light film of oil you can just feel on the surface. A wipe with a clean cloth will show no visible sign of oil on the cloth (maybe smudge of dirt).  In this case, its clear an oil seal has gone.

Side note: It looks like you could do with lower air pressure for the riding you are doing. You have no used anywhere near the full travel of the rear suspension.

Comment: OP may prefer a stiffer shock for pedaling efficiency.

Comment: Many good reasons why a rider has used 50% of the travel he paid for. The Monarch RT does have pedal and fully open settings, might not have switched to full open.  Could also as its his first squishy, hes come off a hardtail  and used to doing the work himself and is not making the most of the rear squash. (I had that problem). Also maybe hes only ridden easy, dusty roads since he last cleaned the shock.  On balance, 150km on a quality soft tail and only using 50% travel in the rear probably worth pointing out.

Comment: Thanks @mattnz! Regarding travel, I've started experimenting with a rather stiff setting not to hurt pedaling efficiency. I'll start softening it little by little. In fact, I find the open rear shock helpful pedaling on rough terrain. Anyway I've cleaned the shaft after some harder descents, but still have some travel left to use so I'll follow your advise!

Comment: bit OT, but this is good. http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/article/how-to-set-up-your-mountain-bike-suspension-32460/